# A new row for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I would like the results to produce a new row in each instance where a condition is met. I'm using a CASE statement but this isn't the way to go since once the first condition is met it stops evaluating the field.

```
SELECT 
Reviews.ReviewID, 
CASE 
    WHEN Score_CorrectID = 0 THEN 'Correct ID Right Party Authentication'  
    WHEN Score_ProperlyIdentified = 0 THEN 'PCA Properly Identified Itself'
    WHEN Score_MiniMiranda = 0 THEN 'Mini-Miranda'          
END AS [Error Type] 
FROM Reviews INNER JOIN PCAs ON Reviews.PCAID = PCAs.PCAID LEFT JOIN 
PCARebuttal ON Reviews.ReviewID = PCARebuttal.ReviewID 
WHERE 
 (Score_CorrectID = 0 OR Score_ProperlyIdentified = 0 OR Score_MiniMiranda = 
0)
```

This produces this:

[image]

I would like this:

[image]

Comment: Please add your source data.

Comment: You want to combine every review ID in the reviews table with all three texts? Or only certain review IDs? What exactly is the task?

Comment: I'd like a separate row for every instance where a Score_x field = 0

Comment: Okay. When working with multiple tables, you should qualify all columns with their table name or alias. Which table does Score_CorrectID reside in for instance? Then what are the tables' keys? Each review has one PCA and multiple PCARebuttals it seems. However, aren't PCAs and PCARebuttals also connected? You select them as if there where completely different things. Does a PCARebuttal have a PCAID which you should also join on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
SELECT r.ReviewID, v.error_type
FROM Reviews r INNER JOIN
     PCAs
     ON r.PCAID = PCAs.PCAID LEFT JOIN 
     PCARebuttal pr
     ON r.ReviewID = pr.ReviewID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES (Score_CorrectID, 'Correct ID Right Party Authentication'),  
                   (Score_ProperlyIdentified, 'PCA Properly Identified Itself'),
                   (Score_MiniMiranda, 'Mini-Miranda')
           ) v(score, error_type)
      WHERE score = 0
     ) v        
WHERE (Score_CorrectID = 0 OR Score_ProperlyIdentified = 0 OR Score_MiniMiranda = 0);
```

That said, I would probably just concatenate the values into a single column:

```
SELECT r.ReviewID,
       ( (CASE WHEN Score_CorrectID = 0 THEN 'Correct ID Right Party Authentication; ' ELSE '' END) +  
         (CASE WHEN Score_ProperlyIdentified = 0 THEN 'PCA Properly Identified Itself; ' ELSE '' END) +
         (CASE WHEN Score_MiniMiranda = 0 THEN 'Mini-Miranda;' ELSE '' END)
       ) as error_types
FROM Reviews r INNER JOIN
     PCAs
     ON r.PCAID = PCAs.PCAID LEFT JOIN 
     PCARebuttal pr
     ON r.ReviewID = pr.ReviewID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES ()
           ) v(score, error_type)
      WHERE score = 0
     ) v        
WHERE (Score_CorrectID = 0 OR Score_ProperlyIdentified = 0 OR Score_MiniMiranda = 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `case`, you can use `union all` instead:

```
SELECT 
    Reviews.ReviewID, 
    'Correct ID Right Party Authentication' AS [Error Type] 
FROM Reviews 
    INNER JOIN PCAs ON Reviews.PCAID = PCAs.PCAID 
    LEFT JOIN PCARebuttal ON Reviews.ReviewID = PCARebuttal.ReviewID 
WHERE Score_CorrectID = 0 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    Reviews.ReviewID, 
    'PCA Properly Identified Itself' AS [Error Type] 
FROM Reviews 
    INNER JOIN PCAs ON Reviews.PCAID = PCAs.PCAID 
    LEFT JOIN PCARebuttal ON Reviews.ReviewID = PCARebuttal.ReviewID 
WHERE Score_ProperlyIdentified = 0 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    Reviews.ReviewID, 
    'Mini-Miranda' AS [Error Type] 
FROM Reviews 
    INNER JOIN PCAs ON Reviews.PCAID = PCAs.PCAID 
    LEFT JOIN PCARebuttal ON Reviews.ReviewID = PCARebuttal.ReviewID 
WHERE Score_MiniMiranda = 0
```